# Pyinstaller - Onefile -- Not saving .exe file to the correct path

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller

In order to use Pyinstaller, I downloaded an older version of python (3.6.4), re downloaded pandas and pyinstaller to this specific version of python. Inside the folder where python 3.6.4 I am executing this command (also where the .py file is that I want to turn into a .exe file)

```
(base) C:\Users\Patrick\Python364\Python36>pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed
demo.py
```

but once I execute it, it begins to bundle the files where the other version of python is (3.6.6) in that path which I DONT WANT

```
1062 INFO: Python: 3.6.6 
1062 INFO: Platform: Windows-8.1-6.3.9600-SP0
1077 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Patrick\Python364\Python36\dem
1077 INFO: UPX is not available.
1077 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Patrick\\Python364\\Python36',
 'C:\\Users\\Patrick\\Python364\\Python36']
1077 INFO: checking Analysis
1077 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc
```

....

```
29280 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\users\\patrick\\anaconda3\\lib\\s
ite-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
```

** SEE HOW IT GOES INTO MY OTHER PATH WHERE THE WRONG VERSION OF PYTHON LVIVES**

anyone have a clue how to fix this?

It ends with the "Maximum Recurssion Depth Exceeded Error" which throws when you bundle your .exe file in a newer version of python, which is the whole reason I downloaded an older one to run it out of.

Answer (score 0):

Before you run pyinstaller, you should make sure two things.

1. Make sure your pyinstaller is installed and located under python
   3.6.4.
2. The terminal (cmd) you opened is using the python 3.6.4 not 3.6.6, You can check this by typing `python --version` on cmd. If result shows 3.6.6, you should add path for python 3.6.4 to your computer's environment variable and then reopen cmd. Hope this will help you!

Comment: How do I make sure PyInstaller is installed under 3.6.4? I downloaded it while the path was open (user/python364/Pip install PyInstaller ) and it installed

Comment: @ myheartsgoon idk what else to do - this is my code:                                        (base) C:\Users\Patrick\Python364\Python36>python.exe -m pip install pyinstaller